# How to set require(msg.sender.balance >= msg.value)?

Tags: solidity

I want to set requirement that restrict if user doesn't have ether more than their inputted `msg.value`

So, I wrote require code like this.

```
function send() public payable {
  require(msg.sender.balance >= msg.value);
}
```

But, it doesn't work cause of "VM error:revert".

How it can be??

Comment: That code seems to work fine for me. My guess is the obvious one: the sender does _not_ have more ether remaining than the amount they sent to `send`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe u must use revert function like this:

```
function send() public payable {
    if (msg.value > msg.sender.balance) {revert();}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to share to someone about that. revert(), assert() etc..     https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e

Comment: urwell friends!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function send() public payable {
   if (msg.sender.balance < msg.value) {
            revert();
   }
}
```

Hope it would help you.